# 7400 series CMOS vs 4000 series logic IC

Tags: digital-logic, integrated-circuit, logic-level

I understand the traditional difference between the 7400 series and the 4000 series logic ICs, but since there are CMOS versions of the 7400 series, is there an advantage to use the 7400 CMOS version over the 4000 series chips? Please note I'm not talking about TTL vs CMOS, as that has been discussed thoroughly before. If there is no difference (read significant difference), I'm assuming then that they would be able to interface with each other? I would think the voltage levels for high and low for both CMOS versions would be near identical, but please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: For a start, compare the propagation delay specs for any of the 74xx00 CMOS types to 4000-series. I just checked quad 2-input NAND gates (CD4011B and 74LVC00A) and the improvement is 10x.

Comment: You're saying that the 7400 series is retaining the characteristics of the TTL speeds (or near I suppose), but simply implemented with CMOS technology? As in the 7400s are faster than 4000s?

Comment: The LVC's are much faster than the CD4000's. If you want to check the others, you'll have to download the datasheets yourself.

Comment: Sure I understand that. I was curious about it in a general sense. Just wanted to confirm my suspicions to make sure I understood. Thank you very much

Comment: As I did not see this mentioned in the answers: For a comparison per family, have a look at this Wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic_family You need to scroll down a bit to see a nice table.

Comment: Ah yeah I was looking at that page yesterday, but managed to miss that table. Very helpful stuff; thanks for that

Comment: @bit0fun: there are **several** 74xx CMOS families: C, HC, AC, LVC,... with huge differences among them. Which one do you want to compare to 4000 CMOS?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The difference depends on your system definition. On the one hand, 74HC operates over a limited voltage range, with 6 volts specified as the maximum supply voltage. The CD4000 series, on the other hand, is rated to a maximum of 18 volts, so it may well be easier to use the CD4000 series in a battery-operated system.

If the limited voltage range of the 74HC line is not a problem, the line is much faster. For instance, comparing the CD4011/74HC00 (Quad 2-input NAND gates) gives propagation delays at 5 volts of 90 nsec (typ) vs 7 nsec. For the CD4063 vs the 74HC85 (4-bit magnitude comparator) the numbers are 625 nsec (typ) vs. 63 nsec. The CD40192 4-bit up/down counter has a typical count frequency of 4 MHz, while the 74HC192 goes at 36 MHz.

It's worth keeping in mind that both lines run faster at higher Vdd, so a CD4000 at 15 volts will do better than the numbers here, but the order of magnitude difference is not erased.

And yes, the 74HC series is designed to roughly maintain the speeds of the 7400/74LS00 lines, and often allows drop-in replacement for much lower power.

Comment: There is/was also the 74**C**xx (without the H) line and that one is/was comparable to 4000. All the other more advanced 74xx lines (HC, ACT, LVC, etc.) are of course faster.

Comment: 74HC is definitely not a suitable drop in replacement for 74LS. That's what 74HC**T** is for.

Answer (score 5):

HC7400 runs 2v to 6v supplies (partly TTL compatible)
HCT7400 (fully TTL compatible) runs 5v +/- 0.5v supplies
4000 series runs 3v to 15v (recommended VDD)

so with 5v supply, 4000, HCT7400 and HC7400 are fully compatible

7400 is comparable speed to TTL
4000 is significantly slower